# Currying vs. anonymous function in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions, currying

I was comparing two ways of defining a [higher-order function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions) in Scala:

```
def f1(elem: Int)(other: Int) = (elem == other)

def f2(elem: Int) = (other: Int) => (elem == other)
```

The first one uses [currying](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html) while the second uses an [anonymous function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax).

I am wondering what is the difference, if any, between the two approaches in terms of how Scala implements them and which version is preferable?

**Note**: Scala now has stopped refering to the first approach as *currying* in favour of *multiple parameter lists*. See the linked docs for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implementations are quite different to the Scala compiler. The curried version compiles down to a Java method by un-currying the parameters:

```
def f1(elem: Int, other: Int): Boolean = elem.==(other);
```

The second version is a method that returns an anonymous function (a `Function1`), so their signatures are completely different. Though they can often be used interchangeably within Scala code, there is quite a bit more generated code in the second version:

```
  def f2(elem: Int): Function1 = (new <$anon: Function1>(elem): Function1);

  @SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class anonfun$f2$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcZI$sp with Serializable {
    final def apply(other: Int): Boolean = anonfun$f2$1.this.apply$mcZI$sp(other);
    <specialized> def apply$mcZI$sp(other: Int): Boolean = anonfun$f2$1.this.elem$1.==(other);
    final <bridge> <artifact> def apply(v1: Object): Object = scala.Boolean.box(anonfun$f2$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)));
    <synthetic> <paramaccessor> private[this] val elem$1: Int = _;
    def <init>(elem$1: Int): <$anon: Function1> = {
      anonfun$f2$1.this.elem$1 = elem$1;
      anonfun$f2$1.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
```

I would only *consider* using the second version in cases where I was explicitly looking to work with `Function1` objects. However, I would personally lean towards using the curried version, because you can still get a `Function1` back with partial application of the first. The curried version is just as powerful, but won't create `Function1` objects when you don't need them.

```
scala> f1(1) _
res1: Int => Boolean = <function1>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.  how do you produce java code from scala?  also, would something like `val f3 = (_ : Int) == (_ : Int) ; f3.curried` suffer from the same problem you noted with `f2`?

Comment: You can't really produce legible Java byte code from Scala (but can produce byte code). I used `-Xprint:jvm` to produce the code in my answer, which is one of the last phases of the Scala compiler. `f3.curried` would create _two_ anonymous functions instead of one, so it would produce more byte code than `f2`.